# Laravel 5 - methodnotallowedhttpexception error on POST

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am creating a basic crud to get familiarized with how Laravel functions, and I have the view, edit, delete, index working smooth however when I attempt to "create" I get the following error on submission.

`methodnotallowedhttpexception`

Any idea why I would be getting this? Please let me know if you need any additional code snips.

Here is my blade template for create.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add a Lead</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-container">
          <form method="POST" action="{{ url('leads/create') }}"  role="form">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Primary Phone #">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="source" id="source" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Lead Source">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <input type="submit"  value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | leads                  | leads.store      | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@store                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads                  | leads.index      | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@index                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/create           |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/index            |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | leads/{lead}           | leads.update     | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@update                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/{lead}           | leads.show       | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@show                              | web          |
|        | DELETE    | leads/{lead}           | leads.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@destroy                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/{lead}/edit      | leads.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\LeadsController@edit                              | web          |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | splash                 |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                  |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Bonus Question: How do I add `auth` as middleware to my leads controller so that a user must be logged in to view it?

My routes defined in `web.php` are the following.

```
// Leads
Route::resource('leads','LeadsController');
Route::get('leads/index', function () { return view('leads.index'); });
Route::get('leads/create', function () { return view('leads.create'); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your form submits a post request, while your `leads/create` route is registered as a `GET` route. so either make your form `method="get"` or register your route as post i.e. `Route::post('leads/create', function(){ /* do something here*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

The method of your form is a POST request, however in your routes you only have a get request for the url 'leads/create'.

GET|HEAD  | leads/create

Creating a POST route should fix it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I would add it as a POST route?

Comment: Updated op with routes for leads

Comment: What laravel version are you using? You should have a web.php file in your routes folder. There you can add routes. It should be pretty self explanatory when you get there.

Comment: I have 5.5, and I am familiar with web.php I posted in my OP the routes I have pertaining to the Leads Crud. I tried using Oasma's answer below but it just redirected the page to the index instead of posting the files. `Route::post('leads/create', function(){ return view('leads.index'); });`

Comment: Ok so if you make the route, you will have to direct it to somewhere where the post request can be dealth with.
Route::post('leads/create', function(){ return view('leads.index'); });
Will lead to the view leads.index.
Route::post('leads/create', 'PostController@index');
Will lead you to the index function in the post controller, where you can deal with the post request.
The post data will be in request()->all(), or request('key')